# "Фіранка" - нормативне чи діалектизм?

Tags: вживання-слів, іменники, діалектизми

Знаходжу в [СУМі](http://sum.in.ua/s/firanka):

> **ФІРА́НКА**, и, жін. Шматок тканини або тюлю, яким запинають вікно, двері тощо; занавіска. Зачинив [Начко] вікно, поспускав фіранки (Іван Франко, VI, 1951, 302); На вікнах почеплено тюлеві фіранки (Анатолій Шиян, Переможці, 1950, 35); Проїхала старомодна карета з.. фіранками (Василь Кучер, Золоті руки, 1948, 40).

Однак, у [Словнику лемківської говірки](https://ukrainian_lemko.academic.ru/14197/%D1%84%D1%96%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0) також знаходжу це слово:

> **фіранка**
>   - кы, ж. Пн.
>   Завіска, занавіска густа або прозора біля вікна.

Отже, **фіранка** -це нормативне слово чи діалектизм?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Коротко:

Обидва слова запозичені, обидва слова досить широко вживані, обидва слова нормативні і не діалектичні.

#### Довго:

Спочатку до етимолоґії:

> [ФІРА́НКА](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D1%84%D1%96%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0) «занавіска на вікні». Запозичення з німецької мови.
>
> н. Vórhang (свн. vürhanc, vorhanc) «завіса на вікні» утворене з префікса vor- «перед», спорідненого з псл. *per-, pro-, укр. пере-, про-, і дієслова hängen (двн. hāhan) «висіти».
>
> [ШТО́РА](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%95%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%96%D1%8F/%D1%88%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0). Запозичене з італійської мови, очевидно, за німецьким та французьким посередництвом (н. Store «штора», фр. store «тс.»)
>
> іт. [stora] (літ. stuora) «циновка, мата» продовжує лат. storea «рогожа, циновка, мата», яке пов’язується з лат. sterno «стелю, простеляю», спорідненим із псл. *prosterti «простерти, прослати», укр. просте́рти

Отже, бачимо, що обидва слова запозичені від західноєвропейських мов. Тоді дослідимо окремо слово "фіранка" на згадки у словниках і частотність.

Стаття на [СУМ-11](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A2%D0%BB%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8F/%D1%84%D1%96%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0):

> жін. Шматок тканини або тюлю, яким запинають вікно, двері тощо; занавіска.

Додаю ще [статтю](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/hrinchenko_slovar_ukrainskoi_movy/%D1%84%D1%96%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0) у Грінченка, де російське "штора" перекладається саме так:

> Фіранка, ки, ж. Штора на окнѣ. Фіранки на вікнах. Гн. І. 135.

Так само перекладає [Ніковський](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%84%D1%96%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=8&highlight=on):

> Фіра́нка – штора.

Так само [Шелудько і Садовський](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%84%D1%96%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=4&highlight=on):

> Занавеска – фіра́нка. Штора – фіра́нка;

У [Кримського](https://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D1%84%D1%96%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0&scope=all&dicts=1&highlight=on) це слово зустрічається як переклад "занавески":

> Занаве́ска, -ве́сочка – заві́ска, заві́сочка, фіра́нок (-нку), фіра́нка (-нки).

У частотному словнику кількість згадок "[фіранки](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0/%D1%84%D1%96%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0)" (1168) і "[штори](https://goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0/%D1%88%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0)" (1880) відрізняється менш ніж удвічі, тож обидва слова вже увійшли в українську мову, є питомими, а словники жодне з них розмовним чи діалектичним не вважають.